# React app inherit style for CSS between classes

Tags: css, reactjs

I have an app that has two similar buttons on two pages.
One for going into my search page and the other for going back to the home page, simples.

The issue I have is that I need the `background-image` value to be different but I don't want to duplicate the rest of the styling. How can I inherit or override the `background-image` property.

I have tried the below but it doesn't seem to work and no button is rendered for `.return-home`

Link:

```
<Link
  to='/'
  className="return-home">
</Link>
```

App.css

```
.open-search, .return-home a {
  display: block;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: #2e7d32;
  background-image: url('./icons/add.svg');
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center;
  background-size: 28px;
  box-shadow: 0 3px 6px rgba(0,0,0,0.16), 0 3px 6px rgba(0,0,0,0.23);
  font-size: 0;
}

.return-home a {
  background-image: url('./icons/arrow-back.svg');
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can provide the image in different instances of css selectors.

```
.open-search, .return-home{
  display: block;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: #2e7d32;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center;
  background-size: 28px;
  box-shadow: 0 3px 6px rgba(0,0,0,0.16), 0 3px 6px rgba(0,0,0,0.23);
  font-size: 0;
}

.open-search{
  background-image: url('./icons/add.svg');
}
.return-home{
  background-image: url('./icons/arrow-back.svg');
}
```

Comment: Great!then can you please accept the answer for stack oveflow community